# JIRA: developing a custom plugin for JIRA

Tags: jira

I am trying to come up with a custom plugin for JIRA. The custom plugin supports git notes feature in JIRA dashboard.

My question is, does commercial JIRA support a custom JIRA plugin?

And are any tutorials/best practices for developing custom JIRA plugin?

Comment: you should google it before posting a question like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does commercial jira support custom jira plugin?

Yes. You can write your plugin and upload it in the "Manage Add-ons" section of your admin area.

> are any tutorials/best practices for developing custom jira plugin?

Yes. Take a look at the [JIRA Plugin Guide](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Plugin+Guide) (the link is broken at the moment of this edit, [this link](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started) appears to replace the broken one).

Answer (score 0):

You may also investigate [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search) in order to search any specific plugin that develop by other companies.

Since various plugins had already been developed, those are being leaded to you during development of the plugin.